# Using the specifications of the input for defining the self variables in a class

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a self parameter inside my class and I need to feed one of its arguments based on the size of the input variable in the forward function of the class. To be clearer, this is my class:

```
  from my_folder import encoder

  class my_class(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channel=256):
        super(my_class, self).__init__()
        
        self.encoder = encoder(t=2, h=4, w=6, patch_t=2)
       
    def forward(self, x):
                
        y = self.encoder(x)
        return y
```

I want to select the `t` argument of the `encoder`  class based on the size of the dimension of the `x` in the forward function. Specifically, I want to select `t` based as the size of x[2]. How can I do that?

Comment: Well, how do you call the `forward` function to decide what `x` is?

Comment: @matszwecja ,   I process the videos and the x as the input is a 5D tensor. I call the my_class in the train script as my_class.train()

Comment: the init will be run when you create the model and forward when you run it. So either you know x shape at the begining and it's constant then you can create a second constructor which take a x exemple as input. You could read x dim in forward and create a new encoder but you couldn't train it, so other way would be to choose padding on the axis 2 so that all x are less than t in the dimension

Comment: Basicly you need to make a step back. You can't use `x` from `forward` method, because forward needs `self.encoder` to already be defined. You need to find what x would be *when creating the object* and pass it to the `__init__` method separately..

Comment: You should also name your classes starting with capital letter to improve readability (`MyClass`, `Encoder`), but that's just a side note.

Comment: @matszwecja , thanks for the comments, but it is still ambiguous for me. Can you elaborate your comments in the shape of an answer?

Comment: @ThomaS , thanks for the comment, but it is still ambiguous for me. Can you elaborate your comments in the shape of an answer?

Comment: You would need to provide more context.

Comment: @matszwecja , regarding one of your comments, the point is that I want to feed the encoder object with fixed values but only in the first iteration the size of the x[2] is 2 and the remainder of the iterations it is 16 and I have no idea how to deal with that. Because the volume of the codes are so large, I couldn't bring all of them here.

Comment: the problem is that when you create the encoder(init), it create neurons with weights, and then you update the weights during training(forward is use here).  And the 1st layer neurons are the weight applied to input tensor. So if you set it to 2, there is not enough to handle a 16 size tensor. You can set it to 16, and pad the 1st iteration with 14 zeros. Then 2 neurons will learn only for this iteration and all 16 will learn for iterations with input of size 16

Comment: or you can use two differents 1st layers: one with size 2 on the input dim and one with size 16, but both with same output size. Then during forward read x dimension and use choose the first layer to use. Both 1st layer would be trained separetly though

Comment: @ThomaS , For clarification, you mean using if expression in the forward?

Comment: yes for the second comment of the two (or you can ...). You can use if in pytorch I think (but not in tensorflow)